# How to extract the cases with certain characters

Tags: r

I want to ask a question about regular expression. I want to extract the cases that include only the certain characters.
For example, in the following vector, I want to extract the cases that only include A or B.

```
 d<-c('AAAAAA','BBBBBBBBB','ABAABAAA','ABA','ABC','ABD','AABB?','A(ABBAAB','ABABABA') 
 grep('[A|B]',d,value=T)
```

What I expect to get is the following, how I can achieve this?

```
c('AAAAAA','BBBBBBBBB','ABAABAAA','ABA','ABABABA')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
d[!grepl('[^AB]', d)]
# [1] "AAAAAA"    "BBBBBBBBB" "ABAABAAA"  "ABA"       "ABABABA"
```

which says, exclude all the elements in `d` that contain anything other than "A" or "B".

Comment: What if there is missing in the original vector d?

Comment: What do you mean by "missing"?  Does the expression not give you your desired output?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works in the presented example, but if I include NA in the vector d, NA can't be excluded in the output.

Comment: What I can think of current stage is this one `!is.na(d)&!grepl('[^AB]', d)`

Comment: You wish to exclude all elements in `d` that contain anything other than "A" or "B", or that are `NA`, hence: `d[!(grepl('[^AB]', d) | is.na(d))]`

Comment: Cool, nice solution!